# Allow Excel Macros to Run On a Protected Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro that is not able to run whenever I protect the sheet.

```
Sub ConditionalDisplay()
    With Worksheets("Data Entry")
    If .Range("C13") = "" Then
        .Rows("14:15").Hidden = True
      Else
        .Rows("14").Hidden = .Range("C13") = "lbs/gal"
        .Rows("15").Hidden = .Range("C13") = "g/L"
    End If

    If .Range("C17") = "" Then
        .Rows("18:19").Hidden = True
        Else
            .Rows("18").Hidden = .Range("C17") = "lbs/gal"
            .Rows("19").Hidden = .Range("C17") = "g/L"
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

If it's unprotected it works fine, but protecting the sheet throws an error when I open the workbook as this sub routine is called when the workbook opens.  I saw a couple of websites that reference using the `"Me.Protect Userinterfaceonly:=true"` but so far that has not worked out for me.

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to include the code snipplet that includes the protection of the sheet.

Comment: I actually don't have any code to protect the sheet, I'm simply using the buttons for "Protect" and "Unprotect" worksheet found in the ribbon.

Comment: I'm confused. If you don't use code to protect the sheet, in what way can you determine whether `Userinterfaceonly` doesn't work out for you?

Comment: Unprotect the sheet at the start of your code, then re-protect at the end.

Comment: @TimWilliams That should not be necessary if he manages to protect Userinterfaceonly. I think the question is about how to achieve that.

Comment: Yes, my question is about syntax for Userinterfaceonly.  I'm not sure exactly how to use it.  Can you shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, below is the solution:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets("Data Entry").Protect Userinterfaceonly:=True
    Worksheets("Data Entry").Range("C6:C10") = ""
    Worksheets("Data Entry").Range("C12:C15") = ""
    Worksheets("Data Entry").Range("C17:C19") = ""
ConditionalDisplay
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to the bottom of your Macro before the `End Sub`:

```vb
Sheets("Name of Sheet").Protect Password:="Your Password", _
    UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```